How to prove that $\left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n $ converge uniformly on $[0, 1-\delta]$?
I saw this problem: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx $$
Assuming the limit and integral could be interchanged then we have the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$.
I don't think this function converge uniformly om $[0,1]$ so I restricted the domain to $[0, 1-\delta]$ for some $\delta>0$

Is it a requirement to only use uniformly continuous condition ? Lebesgue's dominated convergence seems straightforward to me.

@ThànhNguyễn Yes this question is about uniformly converge not the limit.

What integral are you using?

@copper.hat Riemman's

Let $f_n(x)= \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n$.
Claim:- $f_{n+1}(x)\le f_n(x)$ for all $x  \in [0,1]$
Proof:- let $x= t^{n(n+1)}$ then $t\in [0,1]$
$$f_n(x)=\left( \frac{{t^{n+1}}+1}{2} \right)^n , \ \ \ \  f_{n+1} (x) = \left( \frac{{t^{n}}+1}{2} \right)^{n+1} $$
We want to prove that $\left( \frac{{t^{n+1}}+1}{2} \right)^n\ge\left( \frac{{t^{n}}+1}{2} \right)^{n+1} $
it is sufficient to prove that $$h(t):=\frac{(t^{n+1}+1)^n}{(t^n+1)^{n+1}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
Note that $h(0)=1, h(1)=\frac 1 2$
$$h'(t)= \frac{n(n+1)t^{n}(t^n+1)^{n+1}(t^{n+1}+1)^{n-1} -n(n+1)t^{n-1} (t^{n+1}+1)^n(t^n+1)^{n} }{(t^n+1)^{2n+2}}$$
$$
= (n(n+1)t^{n-1}(t^n+1)^{n}(t^{n+1}+1)^{n-1} )\cdot \frac{t (t^n+1 )-t^{n+1}-1 }{(t^n+1)^{2n+2}}\le 0 
$$

Dini’s Theorem:- Suppose that $f_n$ is a monotone sequence of continuous functions
on $I := [a, b]$ that converges on $I$ to a continuous function $f$. Then the convergence of the sequence is uniform.


By that we have:-
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx   =\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}dx = \frac{2}{3} $$

There is some big, unexplained leap starting after Proof.

@copper.hat I edited the answer, is it clear now ?

@xpaul I don't understand what you mean.
